# Offline режим в firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

**Дано:** Приложение работающее с firebase.

**Проблема:** Приложение падает при первом запуске **если нет интернета** (*т.к. не успевает кэшировать базу с интернета*). Поясню более подробнее приложение реализовано так, что при первом запуске в базе создается анонимный пользователь и если после отключить интернет, то приложение работает без проблем, но **если это первый запуск и нет интернета** падает с ошибкой **NPE** (*т.к. user null, что и так понятно, нет инета не может зарегистрироваться анонимно*)

**Вопрос:** Как можно реализовать поддержку оффлайн режима при первом запуске приложения и обязательно отсутствии интернета

**Дополнительно:** это все делал как написано в гайдах

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

DatabaseReference scoresRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("scores");
scoresRef.keepSynced(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

1. При первом запуске без интернета **user null** (*т.к. нет интернета*), создаю своего локального пользователя

   ```
   @NonNull
   private String getUid() {
   String userID;
   if (user == null) {
       userID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   } else {
       userID = user.getUid();
   }
   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "userID = " + userID);

   return userID;
   }
   ```
2. При последующих запусках приложения проверяю, если есть интернет и первый запуск был без интернета, то происходит анонимная авторизация и копирование локальных данных в бд, после этого удаляю старую бд скопировав все данные из нее в новую

   ```
   public void moveFirebaseRecord(final DatabaseReference fromPath, final DatabaseReference toPath) {

   fromPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                   if (databaseError != null) {
                       Log.d(LOG_TAG, "moveFirebaseRecord() failed. firebaseError = " + databaseError);
                   } else {
                       fromPath.removeValue();// deleteAll from oldDB 
                       Log.d(LOG_TAG, "moveFirebaseRecord() Great success!");
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
   ```

   }